# How can i emulate two or more recipient address?

Tags: address, multi-signature

https://webbtc.com/scripts/multisig

Above site lists lots of multisig recipient addresses having 
2 or more addresses like below bitcoin mainnet transaction.

> getrawtransaction fe709089a2a2142b82f9f57745452eff0f5feb9d6e02a6ad87b8faf4750c8a16 true
>
> {
>
> "txid": "fe709089a2a2142b82f9f57745452eff0f5feb9d6e02a6ad87b8faf4750c8a16",
>
> ...
>     "vin": [
>       {
>         ...
>       },
>       {
>         ...
>       }
>     ],
>
> "vout": [
>       {
>
> ```
>   "value": 0.00010000,
>   "n": 0,
>   "scriptPubKey": {
>   ...
>     "type": "multisig",
>     "addresses": [
>       "1FE1A8QAF1d9WyLR67h4bZD5Q8gMAHF8Aq",
>       "17mKFkUqi8Q1zLqRjjQZgHWpE4yboBFjbM"
>     ]
>   }
> },
> {
>   "value": 0.00000000,
>   "n": 1,
> ...
> }
> ```
>
> ],
>     ...
>   }

addmultisigaddress offers multisig address composed of below.

> bitcoin-cli addmultisigaddress 2 '["2Mv4H342fBrP6aJWnSem3bstNGqmrsfJkWH", "2NA6BSeYvtaY6iRhx9ZRQdPdsAzHE6E7Kcz", "2N9sxVZHzJGCZGXLhEZ2hNQUXgWLxgHfjFQ"]'
>
> {
>
> "address": "2Mt69kBHVgAeyDcPSYtcuhDmwZGVcfgDBs6",
>
> "redeemScript": 
>   "5221036e92f34d7cef7dd069d3cc41ac4f7aa5d08964a97fad73a9c736d0f62e086d662103a5cafce0576b6af5b963c8208ebbdf6474af31b9b5cbfce0791e3c6d4f6e8cd021029bd48294dede37c6689597ff8f33c3ad7b53eb604a1208da8dd39312825d32d653ae"
>
> "scriptPubKey": "a9140940d70f73f5d7c3291aa5627b2c20ae46fd732387"
>
> }

I created multisig address("2Mt69kBHVgAeyDcPSYtcuhDmwZGVcfgDBs6") above, and sent money to the address using createrawtransaction.

The expected result "vout.scriptPubKey.addresses" tag was

> "addresses":
>
> > [
> >           "2Mv4H342fBrP6aJWnSem3bstNGqmrsfJkWH",
> >           "2NA6BSeYvtaY6iRhx9ZRQdPdsAzHE6E7Kcz",
> >          "2N9sxVZHzJGCZGXLhEZ2hNQUXgWLxgHfjFQ",
> >      ],

but the result was

> "addresses": [
>         "2Mt69kBHVgAeyDcPSYtcuhDmwZGVcfgDBs6"
>      ],

Comment: see also example from Gavin: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gavinandresen/3966071/raw/1f6cfa4208bc82ee5039876b4f065a705ce64df7/TwoOfThree.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fe709089a2a2142b82f9f57745452eff0f5feb9d6e02a6ad87b8faf4750c8a16](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/fe709089a2a2142b82f9f57745452eff0f5feb9d6e02a6ad87b8faf4750c8a16) is not paying out to a P2SH multisig address. It is paying out to a bare multisig address.

With your commands, you are creating a multisig address wrapped inside a P2SH address. What you have is a HASH160(redeeemScript). What you want is just an output going to `n <pub1> <pub2> .... m OP_CHECKMULTISIG`.

Do note that bare multisigs are rarely used these days, and nodes may reject the transaction (although it is still valid if mined). You should be using a P2SH address.

Comment: thanks, the term "bare multisig" would be a hint to solve.